# aws-amplify auth currentSession returns no current user

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, promise, async-await, aws-amplify

Use: Nodejs + aws-amplify

From the [aws amplify documentation](https://aws-amplify.github.io/docs/js/authentication), but I have not successfully checked user after they signed in.

**index.js**

```
const Amplify = require('aws-amplify');
global.fetch = require('node-fetch'); // [source](https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-js/issues/876)
global.navigator = {};

Amplify.default.Auth({
    identityPoolId: IDENTITYPOOLID,
    region: REGION,
    userPoolId: USERPOOLID,
    userPoolWebClientId: APPCLIENTID,
});

Amplify.Auth.signIn(username, password).then(user => {
    localstorage.set('user', JSON.stringify(user));
    console.log(user); // "cognitoUser" object
    return Amplify.Auth.getSession();
}).then(session => {
    console.log(session); // "CognitoSession" object
}).catch(err => {
    console.log(err);
});

// PROBLEM
Amplify.Auth.getSession().then(session => {
    console.log(session);
}).catch(err => {
    console.log(err); // PRINT: no current user
});
```

It looks like I cannot get user session, unless it is wrapped inside `Auth.signIn`. I tried to use;

```
// Problem
let userObj = JSON.parse(localstorage.get('use'));
Amplify.Auth.userSession(userObj).then(data => {
    console.log(data);
});
/// getSession is not a function

console.log(Amplfy.Auth.userSession); // PRINT: [Function]
```

I can verify that userSession is function and inside the lib, and the problem i see is that `getSession()` is not inside the CognitoUser object I store in the localstorage.

I cannot find any functions that help me convert the localstorage object to CognitoObj if that is the problem. The only thing i can do is signing user in each time which is neglect the whole purpose of this lib.

Have I missed something? why is `Amplify.Auth` does not work? Is there a way I can check either user's session is not expired and manually refresh it?

I have similiar issue to [github](https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-js/issues/399).

Answer (score 2):

> It looks like I cannot get user session, unless it is wrapped inside Auth.signIn

That's the Node/JS async programming model in a nutshell. If you have some temporal dependency between asynchronous actions, you have to wrap the later actions in callbacks or `then`, and/or conversely the earlier actions in `await`ed promises.

In fact, if you have some asynchronous operations that can be run concurrently / have no dependencies between each other, you can optimize your code with the [Promise.all API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) so that it sends all async requests at the same time and resolves when the last one finishes.

[Top-level await](https://v8.dev/features/top-level-await) will probably help resolve use cases like this.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem and I ended up writing like this.

```
import Auth from "@aws-amplify/auth";
Auth.currentAuthenticatedUser().then((user) => {
  const session = user.getSignInUserSession();
  if (session) {
    AWS.config.credentials = new AWS.CognitoIdentityCredentials({
      IdentityPoolId: "REGION:POOL_ID",
      Logins: {
        "cognito-idp.REGION.amazonaws.com/ID": session
          .getIdToken()
          .getJwtToken(),
      },
    });
  }
});
```